# SQL DISTINCT incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, distinct

I've got this problem and I have no idea how to solve it:

```
SELECT    CONVERT(tinyint, 1) AS field,  DISTINCT (B, C, D)
FROM      TableA 
WHERE     (F <> '')
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using? `DISTINCT` is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: Is there something you don't understand?  The syntax is `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats not at all how you use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

The usage syntax for the `DISTINCT` keyword is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

So in your case that would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT   CONVERT(tinyint, 1) AS field, B, C, D
FROM      TableA 
WHERE     (F <> '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(tinyint, 1), * FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT B, C, D FROM TableA WHERE     (F <> '')
)AS req
```